# Change SQL Server Pass Through Query Variable

Tags: vba, ms-access, pass-through, jet-sql

So I have a SQL Server pass through query in MS-Access that I created with the query design. I just double click it and it runs and opens up in datasheet view. Then I can export it. The query looks like so:

```
DECLARE @acyr AS varchar(4);
 SELECT @acyr = '2018'

SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE year = @acyr
```

I also have a form with a listBox labeled acyrList where the user picks from 2017, 2018, 2019. I would like for acyrList.Value to be passed to the @acyr in the pass through query and return the records for that year.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rebuild the SQL in the Click event for the listbox and then assign that SQL to the pass through query.  Something like:

```
Private Sub acyrList_Click()
  Dim strSQL As String
  strSQL = "DECLARE @acyr AS varchar(4); " & _
           "SELECT @acyr = '" & acyrList.value & "'; " & _
           "SELECT * From Table WHERE year = @acyr;"

  'MsgBox strSQL
  CurrentDb.QueryDefs("passthrough_query_name").sql = strSQL
End Sub
```